# How to drop_duplicates in a balanced way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to drop duplicates from a dataframe in a balanced way. Currently `df.drop_duplicates()` have the parameter `keep` where you can determine to keep the first or the last occurence. Instead of this solution, I would like to keep the occurrences in a distributed way.

I.e. I have this dataframe, with two columns: text and category, which looks balanced but have duplicates:
[image: dataframe]

Applying `drop_duplicates()` and plotting again, will look like this:

```py
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='text')
df['Category'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: dataframe_drop]

The expected result will be the dataframe without the duplicates, with all the columns. But instead of keeping the last occurence or the first one (because this will produce an unbalanced dataframe, due the most occurences could be in the first or last category), keep the dataframe as balanced as possible (since depending on the number of duplicates, there could be some odd categories, that is, it does not need to be 100% balanced).

Comment: Would that mean that you allow in your expected result some categories still having duplicates in order to have balance between categories?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart no, drop all of them

Answer (score 0):

To maintain balance after dropping duplicates you need to down sample all categories greater than the minimum (neg_hp). However I assume `sadness` might be a better minimum point. You can do that by

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='text')
max_sample = df[df['Category'].eq('sadness')]
```

Then sample `max_sample` from all other categories

`df['Category'].eq('conifident').sample(max_sample)`

That way all your categories will have the same `value_counts`

Comment: this is similar to this [function](https://gist.github.com/Y4rd13/1fe2b2fd42943ab9a57f3fa5838a50ac), right?

Comment: in this function I will get the dataframe balanced having as reference the category 
with minimum value

Comment: Im not looking to do this after dropping the duplicates, Im looking a way to apply it in such a way where all the categories are kept. Right now the categories are dropped, because is keeping the first occurence.

Comment: @Y4RD13 yes but that's a very inefficient function, you shouldn't have to loop through a df (iterrows) to fix balance issues

Comment: Im not sure how a categorie is dropped with drop duplicates since at least one occurrence will stay